# when run with tf-tutorials it happened:AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.estimator.api.estimator' has no attribute 'SessionRunHook'

Tags: python, tensorflow-estimator

i'm recurrenting with tensorflow official tutorials about estimator when it happened the above error, while it runs properly in google.colab.

the environment i used were win10-64bit & tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0 & python==3.6.6.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.feature_column as fc
import os
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
tf.enable_eager_execution()

models_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'models')
sys.path.append(models_path)

from official.wide_deep import census_dataset
from official.wide_deep import census_main
```

this is the error info:

```
D:\python\python.exe F:/hupnos/PycharmProject/estimator/linear_model.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/hupnos/PycharmProject/estimator/linear_model.py", line 13, in <module>
    from official.wide_deep import census_dataset
  File "F:\hupnos\PycharmProject\estimator\models\official\wide_deep\census_dataset.py", line 31, in <module>
    from official.utils.flags import core as flags_core
  File "F:\hupnos\PycharmProject\estimator\models\official\utils\flags\core.py", line 30, in <module>
    from official.utils.flags import _base
  File "F:\hupnos\PycharmProject\estimator\models\official\utils\flags\_base.py", line 25, in <module>
    from official.utils.logs import hooks_helper
  File "F:\hupnos\PycharmProject\estimator\models\official\utils\logs\hooks_helper.py", line 29, in <module>
    from official.utils.logs import hooks
  File "F:\hupnos\PycharmProject\estimator\models\official\utils\logs\hooks.py", line 28, in <module>
    class ExamplesPerSecondHook(tf.estimator.SessionRunHook):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.estimator.api.estimator' has no attribute 'SessionRunHook'
```

Comment: is there any one can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same on tf 1.12. the 1.13 api doc does include SessionRunHook

```
in <module>
    class ExamplesPerSecondHook(tf.estimator.SessionRunHook):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.estimator.api.estimator' has no attribute 'SessionRunHook'
```

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.__version__)
1.12.0
>>>
```